# how to change default dataTables position

Tags: jquery

I am working on a project in codeigniter in which I've used jQuery dataTables. In the project I've used the `position` property of css. 
I want to make this dataTable position static.

I have tried some techniques on jQuery initialization but it has some problem in initialization.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my_table').DataTable({
      "th": [{
        "position": "static"
      }]
    });
  });
</script>
```

How can I make the dataTable's position static?

Comment: I dont understand. If you want to make the whole tables position static, just make the parent div (or whatever) static

Comment: you want whole datatable as fixed or table column's header as fixed?  as in code you are trying to fix "th"

Comment: sir i want this whole datatable as static. i already made the parent div static it works for every thing else but when it comes to jquery tables when i scroll down every thing in the datatable just overcome the fixed data header and navigation section.